# How can I set openFileOutput mode to MODE_PRIVATE and MODE_APPEND?

Tags: android, file

Why do I have to choose between `MODE_PRIVATE` and `MODE_APPEND` for

```
openFileOutput(String name, int mode)
```

? How can I set both?

Answer (score 14):

Just OR the two constants:

```
openFileOutput(name, MODE_PRIVATE | MODE_APPEND);
```

Also MODE_PRIVATE is defined as 0 (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_PRIVATE) so even omitting it completely from the line above will have the desired effect. I usually just add it with OR for better readability.